# ASA traceroute from lower security level to higher security level

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, security

In following scenarios Security Level `50` (dmz-1) to Security level `75` (dmz-2) traceroute not working. I think traceroute use specific port for unreachable function but in following scenario i don't know which udp port it's going to pick.

[image]

I have following config

```
access-list DMZ-1-IN extended permit icmp any any unreachable
access-list DMZ-1-IN extended permit icmp any any time-exceeded
access-list DMZ-1-IN extended permit icmp any any traceroute
!
access-group DMZ-1-IN in interface dmz-1
!
class class-default
  set connection decrement-ttl
```

## Update:

Here are the logs

```
Oct 20 2017 09:47:04: %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src dmz-1:10.5.8.40/48236 dst dmz-1:10.5.16.40/33434 by access-group "DMZ-1-IN" [0x0, 0x0]
Oct 20 2017 09:47:04: %ASA-4-106023: Deny udp src dmz-2:10.5.8.40/53052 dst dmz-2:10.5.16.40/33435 by access-group "DMZ-1-IN" [0x0, 0x0]
```

Comment: One question: are you able to do this from inside interface? Please add two lines below and try again: `access-list DMZ-1-IN extended permit icmp any any echo-reply` ! `icmp unreachable rate-limit 50 burst-size 6`. When you traceroute again from dmz-1 host, check for your firewall logs with command `show logging | i dmz-1_host_IP_address` to see if the ASA denies/blocks traceroute traffic from that dmz-1 host or not.

Comment: @HungTran ASA denying because `traceroute` because it is using random `UDP` port and in my access list only specific ports are allowed, if i do `permit udp any any` then it works! so it's clear you need to open udp port range for it, but if i use `traceroute -p 80 <ip>` it works, because port 80 is opened.

Comment: I can able to traceroute from `dmz-2` to `dmz-1` because higher security level to lower is pretty much open path.

Comment: Did you try to traceroute from Cisco devices or from laptop/PC?

Comment: And please share the denied/dropped block messages related to this.

Comment: I did traceroute from Linux machine. I have updated logs too in my question

Comment: Got it! Let me put this in the answer part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to update your ACL to allow more UDP ports covering the traceroute packets from Unix-like Operating system.

According to the [Wikipedia Page for Traceroute:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)

- On Unix-like Operating Systems, traceroute sends (by default) a sequence of UDP packets with destination port range: 33434 - 33534.
- On Windows Operating Systems, traceroute sends ICMP echo requests instead of UDP packets. That is why when you traceroute from a Windows host, you do not face this issue.

So, you need to update your ACL with the following rule to allow destination UDP ports when tracerouting from your Linux/Unix/like hosts and servers:

```
access-list DMZ-1-IN extended permit udp any any range 33434 33534
```

I hope it is helpful and answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

Updated:

The two requirements are:

- Inspect ICMP from the inside -> outside
- Allow ICMP time-exceeded inbound from outside

  access-list OUTSIDE_IN remark *** ALLOW ICMP BASED TRACEROUTE ***
  access-list OUTSIDE_IN extended permit icmp any any time-exceeded

  access-group OUTSIDE_IN in interface Outside

  class-map inside-inspection
   match default-inspection-traffic

  policy-map inside-policy
   class inside-inspection
    inspect icmp

  service-policy inside-policy interface Inside

---

The following example permits host 172.16.2.15 or hosts on subnet 172.22.1.0/16 to receive echo-reply messages at the outside interface:

```
 hostname(config)# icmp permit host 172.16.2.15 echo outside 
 hostname(config)# icmp permit 172.22.1.0 255.255.0.0 echo outside 
 hostname(config)# icmp permit any unreachable outside
```

This is an example from https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/i1.html#wp1697623